# How to configure Grails gorm save to not fetch all associations?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.5.4

I notice that if I call a domain object's save(), Grails tries to fetch all of the object's associations one by one.  So for example with a set up like:

```
class Person {
    String name 

    static hasMany = [comments: Comment] 
}
```

When I run code like this:

```
Person p = Person.get(1234)
p.save()
```

And look at the hibernate log, I see that before actually updating p, Grails tries to fetch every comment associated with p, one query per comment, and the save has terrible performance, even if all I am trying to do might be to update p's address.

Is there any way to configure the domain object so that the association is ignored by save(), since clearly I will ever only save Comment with its own save service (Something like `commentService.addComment(params)`), and never when I am updating Person?

I don't want to fetch the comments eagerly when I fetch Person.  I know that would solve the lazy loading issue, but that's not ideal.  All I am trying to do is updating some field values on the Person object, while completely ignoring any mapped associations.  So there is no reason to fetch the associations.

Comment: "Grails tries to fetch all of the object's associations one by one" - Does "one by one" mean that if you have 20 associations, 20 different `select` statements are being sent to the database?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am seeing in the log.

Comment: I don't understand that.  There may be something in the model or in the way the data is being manipulated that is relevant but not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Would be strange to send a separate `select` statement to the database to retrieve each individual association.  If you can reproduce that in a sample app, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues linking to the app and we can investigate it.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> And look at the hibernate log, I see that before actually updating p,
>   Grails tries to fetch every comment associated with p, one query per
>   comment, and the save has terrible performance

I am not able to reproduce that. See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/peterchou.

**Comment.groovy**

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/Comment.groovy
package demo

class Comment {
    String text
}
```

**Person.groovy**

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/Person.groovy
package demo

class Person {
    String name
    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
}
```

**BootStrap.groovy**

```
// grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy
import demo.*

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        println 'Before saving instance'
        def p = new Person(name: 'Peter')
            .addToComments(text: 'Comment One')
            .addToComments(text: 'Comment Two')
            .addToComments(text: 'Comment Three')
            .save(flush: true)

        println 'Before retrieving instance'

        def p2 = Person.get(p.id)

        println 'Before updating instance'
        p2.name = 'Peter Chou'
        p2.save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

When run, that creates the following output:

```
Before saving instance
Hibernate: insert into person (id, version, name) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (id, version, text) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (id, version, text) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (id, version, text) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person_comment (person_comments_id, comment_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person_comment (person_comments_id, comment_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person_comment (person_comments_id, comment_id) values (?, ?)
Before retrieving instance
Before updating instance
Hibernate: update person set version=?, name=? where id=? and version=?
```

**EDIT:**

I added a controller at https://github.com/jeffbrown/peterchou/commit/8c1f6a289cc0a6cff54e5b9fb9d1fed3e19b9760 which looks like this:

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy
package demo

class DemoController {

    def index() {
        def p = Person.get(1)
        def numberOfComments = p?.comments?.size()
        p.name = "Name With Time: ${new Date()}"
        p.save(flush: true)

        render "Person has ${numberOfComments} comments."
    }
}
```

When invoked, that sends 1 query to the database to retrieve the `Person` instances, another query to retrieve the `Comment` instances and finally sends an update to the `person` table.

```
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_1_0_, person0_.version as version2_1_0_, person0_.name as name3_1_0_ from person person0_ where person0_.id=?
Hibernate: select comments0_.person_comments_id as person_c1_1_0_, comments0_.comment_id as comment_2_2_0_, comment1_.id as id1_0_1_, comment1_.version as version2_0_1_, comment1_.text as text3_0_1_ from person_comment comments0_ inner join comment comment1_ on comments0_.comment_id=comment1_.id where comments0_.person_comments_id=?
Hibernate: update person set version=?, name=? where id=? and version=?
```

Comment: Thank you.  I just tested with a fresh project and also do not encounter the issue.  So some configuration in the existing project must have caused the unwanted behavior.  I will post if/when I have figured that out.

Comment: The issue turns out to be that there is a service saving a subset of domain objects to a separate mongo DB.  I find that if I remove the mongodb grails plugin dependency, the issue goes away.  So, I believe what I have to do is to figure out how to configure the plugin to ignore the saves on domain objects that do not persist to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

as you can read from Burt Beckwith's blog post at https://mrpaulwoods.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/implementing-burt-beckwiths-gorm-performance-no-collections/

having a hasMany from Person to Comment would at least fetch all Comments when adding a new one.

so, perhaps structuring your code like this could help?

```
class Person {
    String name 

    static transients = ['comments']

    Collection<Comment> getComments() {
        Comment.findAllByPerson(this)
    }
}
```

the Comment should still have a belongsTo to Person:

```
class Comment {
    static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}
```

and when creating a new Comment, instead of

```
person.addToComments(...)
```

simply do

```
new Comment(person: person, ...).save()
```